# expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

below is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

i am still getting error

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'firefox_binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line

Comment: using firefox - 50.0.2 version and python - 3.5, geckodriver - v0.10.0

Comment: Look at the comment on this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088288/how-to-set-up-python-3-selenium-geckodriver-for-firefox-on-windows-10)