# How to set up Python 3 Selenium/Geckodriver for Firefox on Windows 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

Saw a lot of people have had problems like this, but in all my searches I saw a lot of conflicting and confusing information that I didn't understand - this is all a bit out of my newbie depth.

I installed Selenium in PyCharm and was attempting to run this code from the book Automate The Boring Stuff with Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://inventwithpython.com')
linkElem = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Read It Online')
type(linkElem)
linkElem.click() # follows the "Read It Online" link
```

Running it throws the following exceptions:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\LB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "C:\Users\LB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\LB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/LB/Desktop/PythonProjects/AutomateTheBoringStuffProjects/generalTestingFile.py", line 2, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Users\LB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 142, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\LB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

I've downloaded the latest `geckodriver.exe` (specifically the 64bit version since I'm on 64bit OS but I'm running 32bit Firefox if that's okay?), but I'm not sure where to put it.

I've looked up how to change a PATH but I don't know what exactly I'm supposed to change or where it's supposed to point to. (Firefox folders? Python folders?)

Comment: Followed someone's advice to put geckodriver.exe in C:\Users\LB\ and edit the System Path (https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/) to ADD that location to the Variable called Path. And now the code works! (You can apparently put geckodriver.exe anywhere, as long as you point the path to that specific folder.)

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question instead of posting it in a comment

Answer (score 0):

Followed someone's advice to put `geckodriver.exe` in `C:\Users\LB\` and edit the System Path to ADD that location to the Variable called Path. And now the code works! (You can apparently put geckodriver.exe anywhere, as long as you point the path to that specific folder.)

Source: https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/

---

<sub>This answer was posted as a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088288/how-to-set-up-python-3-selenium-geckodriver-for-firefox-on-windows-10#comment75199024_44088288) to the question [How to set up Python 3 Selenium/Geckodriver for Firefox on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088288/how-to-set-up-python-3-selenium-geckodriver-for-firefox-on-windows-10) by the OP [LBoot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7902878/lboot).</sub>